# SQL Query for chats table for sqlite3 and mysql

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have a simple chat table with:

```
id, sender_id, sender_name, recipient_id, recipient_name, content
```

Trying to group all chats that have happened between `Person A` (me) and (someone else) OR (someone else) and `Person A`

How would someone do this ?

### EDIT

Goal is to get list with all Chats where Person A is in and only list the other people.

i.e. If Person A has chats with Person B, Person C and Person D I want to show a list with Person B, Person C and Person D.  Then in the next view I will show the chats with Person A and someone else.

Comment: What do you mean with "group"? Just display the content for the chats? Also, having both sender_id and sender_name in your chat table indicates you are saving the sender_name double, once in the user table and once in your chat table.

Comment: @cularis is correct.. notice the ambiguity in the reponses about which is the proper key.

Comment: Sorry, Do have id as well.  edited question

Comment: cularis, you are right saving name twice.  Doing this for mobile query so I do not have to query local DB twice per chat.  Figured, use a little more space in DB in return faster response.  Still in dev stage so can remove if need be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from chat where
recipient_id in (persona, personb )
and sender_id in ( persona, personb )
```

EDIT:

Technically, you are not really 'grouping' in the SQL sense, you may be Ordering the results.

something like this:

```
select id, content, sender_id as other_person
from chat 
where recipient_id = persona
union
select id, content, recipient_id
from chat 
where sender_id = persona
order by other_person
```

also, please do consider normalizing now rather that later.  your idea of 'not querying twice' is not correct.  it will be better to not repeat the names.

Comment: OK, so I get all "Chats" that are between 2 people, but in the step before this one, I would have a list with all conversations where `select * from chat where recipient_id IS (persona) OR sender_id IS (persona)`.  So this lists persona conversations with personb, personc and persond, but how can I group by personb, personc and persond

Comment: Randy can you please explain what the "AS" is?  Trying to find docs or samples to better understand.  And will remove duplication of names in table.

Comment: it just aliases the column with a new name.  you can omit it as weel and the second word will be assumed to be the desired column alias.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM chatTable
WHERE sender_name IN('personA','personB') AND
recipient_name IN('personA','personB');
```

Comment: the OR is not quite right.  this would get ll chats from person B to anyone else also.. for instance.